# Rounding up long decimal point

Tags: c#

I don't know the correct terminology to explain this, I have decimal digits come back from an api that look like:

[image: sample cicture] 
(example: 22.778654357658)

I don't need any data after the decimal point, in the example above it would just be the 22 value I need, I could to it with regex but it seems a bit messy, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: do you want rounding, or do you want integer truncation? For integer truncation - see Kevin's answer below.

Comment: You mentioned the decimal digits but did not mention whether the value is an string or a decimal. Did you see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx

Comment: @EtherDragon for me it looks like integer truncation because of the given example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Title suggests rounding up but you're describing rounding down. Here's some options:

If it's a string and you just want the 22 (round down, not up), then using IndexOf is fastest. This works as expected with negatives too:

```
string theNumber = "22.7685857856";

int pointLocation = theNumber.IndexOf('.');

int theRoundedDownNumber = int.Parse(theNumber.Substring(0,pointLocation)); // 22
```

If it's not a string - i.e. you've got a `double`, `float` or `Decimal`, then these are better (I'm assuming you're actually using double here rather than the 'decimal' data type; the functions are the same either way however):

To round *up* (22.77 -> 23):

```
double yourNumber = 22.7685857856;

yourNumber = Math.Ceiling(yourNumber);
```

To round *down* (22.77 -> 22):

```
double yourNumber = 22.7685857856;

yourNumber = Math.Floor(yourNumber);
```

To just round it (22.77 -> 23; 22.4 -> 22):

```
double yourNumber = 22.7685857856;

yourNumber = Math.Round(yourNumber);
```

If your number is a string ("22.7685857856") but you'd like to use these functions then you'll need to parse it first:

```
double yourNumber = double.Parse("22.7685857856");
```

(Or double.TryParse)

**However,** If your numbers can contain negatives then things get a little interesting as Floor and Ceiling will "go the wrong way" for a negative number. For rounding down (Floor), Casting it to an integer is a simple way around that one:

```
double yourNumber = 22.7685857856;

// -22.4 -> -22 and 22.4 -> 22
int yourNumberInt = (int)yourNumber;
```

For rounding up, the safest route is an if:

```
if( yourNumber > 0 )
{
    // 22.7 -> 23
    yourNumber = Math.Ceiling(yourNumber);
}
else
{
    // -22.4 -> -23
    yourNumber = Math.Floor(yourNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way use a cast?

```
int x = (int) 22.7685857856;
```

Or if you only want to remove the decimal places:

```
decimal y = Decimal.Floor(22.7685857856m);
```

Or if you want to round correct and return a `string`:

```
string result = 22.7685857856m.ToString("N0");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.  One way is to use `string.split('.')[0]) to grab the part of the string to the left of the decimal point and then convert that to an integer.

```
string s = "22.77";
int x = Convert.ToInt32(s.Split('.')[0]);
```

Another way would be to use Math.Floor, but that gets a bit messier because it returns type `decimal` and you might want to cast again to `int`.

```
string s = "22.77";
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDecimal(s)));
```

**Edit:** Actually, you might want to steer clear of the second method because `Math.Floor` always rounds down, rather than just discarding digits after the decimal.  That means that 22.77 rounds down to 22.0, but -22.77 rounds down to -23.0.